# Apache Beam - PubSub Message to several BigQuery tables based on a field

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a pipeline that load PubSub message from a topic into a BigQuery table. In order to process less data, I want to store message based on the "customer_id" field into a BigQuery table called table-{customer_id}. However, I am struggling a lot to find out how to do it correctly.

Below, you will find my pipeline that is working but does not write into several tables.

```
public class PubsubAvroToBigQuery {

    public interface Options extends PipelineOptions, StreamingOptions {
        @Description("The Cloud Pub/Sub topic to read from.")
        @Required
        ValueProvider<String> getInputTopic();

        void setInputTopic(ValueProvider<String> value);

        @Description("BigQuery Table")
        @Required
        ValueProvider<String> getBigQueryTable();

        void setBigQueryTable(ValueProvider<String> value);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);
        options.setStreaming(true);

        try {
            run(options);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static PipelineResult run(Options options) throws IOException {
        // Create the pipeline
        options.setStreaming(true);
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
        // load avro schema from classpath
        Schema avroSchema = ApiCalls.SCHEMA$;

        pipeline
                .apply(
                        "Read PubSub Avro Message",
                            PubsubIO.readAvroGenericRecords(avroSchema).fromTopic(options.getInputTopic())
                )
                .apply("Write to BigQuery", BigQueryIO.<GenericRecord>write()
                        .to(options.getBigQueryTable())
                        .useBeamSchema()
                        .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                        .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                        .optimizedWrites());

        return pipeline.run();
    }

}
```

I did lot of test based on TupleTag or even Windows (with data grouped) but it didn't work...
Hope you can help me
Thank you

Comment: The class-level docs for BigQueryIO provide an intro on dynamic writes which should be pretty relevant to your use case. See "Writing different values to different tables" in the [BigQueryIO javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.40.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html). In particular, the `to` method can take a function that determines output table name based on contents of the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your Use Case, you could use the [DynamicDestinations class](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.43.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/DynamicDestinations.html) to chose the [TableDestination](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.43.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/TableDestination.html) to use according to the input event.

You can use it, as stated in the Javadoc like this:

```java
 events.apply(BigQueryIO.<UserEvent>write()
  .to(new DynamicDestinations<UserEvent, String>() {
        public String getDestination(ValueInSingleWindow<UserEvent> element) {
          // here read your input and extract the customer_id
          return element.getValue().getUserId();
        }
        public TableDestination getTable(String user) {
          // here build the destination table based on what is output by getDestination method
          return new TableDestination(tableForUser(user), "Table for user " + user);
        }
        public TableSchema getSchema(String user) {
          return tableSchemaForUser(user);
        }
      })
  .withFormatFunction(new SerializableFunction<UserEvent, TableRow>() {
     public TableRow apply(UserEvent event) {
       return convertUserEventToTableRow(event);
     }
   }));
```

Note that you can create a class that implements DynamicDestinations with a constructor to pass parameters that could then be used in the implemented methods.